# Should I get Adobe Photoshop for graphic design, graphic illustrations, illustrations, art and painting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, illustration, art, games

I have always wanted to get Photoshop because of all it's features(video, 3D etc.) but I mostly use it on game design and graphic design. I **won't** be using it for photography since I'm not a photographer and not into photo manipulation. Is photoshop good for graphic design, illustrations, graphic illustrations, art and painting? I know there is Adobe Illustrator and it has intrested me but it doesn't have the amount of features Photoshop has in term of creating videos, painting and creating 3D items.

Thanks.

Comment: You can get a trial. Just a few days ago a student complained that illustrator has morecfeatures then photoshop. Anyway features dobt make the end product. The 3D features of photoshop are so weak that you may just ignore them. Anyway the vide features are quirky and moderately useful

Comment: To answer your question, it's alright. Like any other software.

Comment: Photoshop and Illustrator aren't *really* comparable. They each do different things. One is a *raster* editor and the other is a *vector* editor.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of misinformation/urban myth about Photoshop. You'll often hear people say things such as "That video was photoshopped" when referring to incredible cgi effects, or basically for any artwork that has obviously been created digitally. Often it's simply not true. However, it is the industry standard raster image editor. Other similar software also exists of course, such as GIMP, Affinity Photo, Corel PaintShop Pro, etc.

Sure graphic designers and artists can and do use Photoshop, but it's definitely not suitable or the best for everything. Photoshop was primarily designed for editing raster images such as photographs, hence the name. That is what it excels at.

Apart from photo editing, Photoshop can also be used for the following:

1. Digital painting/drawing.  It's good for when you need painterly effects, simulating natural media, textures, blurs etc. However, IMHO it's not the best digital painting software out there. Some software is specifically designed for that purpose, such as Krita, Clip Studio Paint, Corel Painter, etc.
2. Basic video editing and animation. Nothing as complex as dedicated video editing or video effects software such as AfterEffects, or advanced animated 3D and cgi video effects created in Blender, Maya, Cinema4D, etc.
3. Basic rendering of 3D models created in 3D software. Photoshop can also create basic 3D text, and basic shapes natively, however you can't actually model in 3D, or edit 3D models. For that you'll need dedicated 3D software, like Blender, Maya, Cinema4D, etc.  Photoshop can import 3D models in .obj format.  Note also that Adobe doesn't actually make any 3D modelling software.
4. Basic vector work, however it lacks many of the standard features you'll find in dedicated vector software such as Illustrator, Inkscape, CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, etc.

Photoshop can also be used for other non-graphic design related work, such as image enhancement for scientific research, forensic analysis etc, but I won't go into those in any depth, since those have little to do with graphic design.

Also you shouldn't really try to compare Photoshop with Adobe Illustrator. One is raster based, the other is vector. They are used for different kinds of work. Illustrator is the industry standard vector image editor when it comes to things like logo design, info graphics, vector artwork for print, etc.

Comment: Adobe is fewerishly trying to get into 3D after all thats why the aquired substance painter. But they have a 15 year track record of not getting 3D software users. To be honest if adobe could ditch beziers for b-splines they would be there almost instantly. Not going to happen though.

Answer (score 0):

First, this isn't something which everyone here would fully agree upon:

> it doesn't have the amount of features Photoshop has in term of
> creating videos, painting and creating 3D items.

Apart from videos (it doesn't support video editing), Illustrator also has 3D options. You can do illustration/art and some kind of painting too which you can do in Photoshop.

Now, Photoshop can be a good option for you for graphic illustrations, art and painting (all digital of course). It depends on whether you get used to it or not.

Photoshop isn't just for Photographers. People from many different professions use it. So it's absolutely okay to use it for graphic design/illustration/art.

I have not tried much of video features of Photoshop, but yes, you can create basic animations or video editing in Photoshop. I have tried GIFs and basic animations. But I guess you can't expect much from it for video editing.

Given all that, if you're more into graphic art, design and illustration, you can use any of them. Each would have their own pros and cons. It depends on what **kind of work** you are going to do.

For example, *Logo Design* and *export for print with more flexible options* are probably done better in Illustrator. An image manipulation based ad design can have some advantages in Photoshop. So ask yourself questions like these:

- What kind of work you'd spend your most time on?
- Will you miss something important if you prefer one over other? What could be compromised?
- Pricing. In my country, Adobe's *Photography* plan is a bit cheaper than Illustrator alone. (But I haven't tried it so I'm not sure what kind of work you're allowed with Photography plan and license. You'd need to find out pros and cons for that.). So you can consider your budget too while making decision.
- Game design part - I don't know about game designs. So you have to figure out which app could be better for it or which one is used the most. So again, it depends on the kind of work you are going to do.

Comment: Hi. When you say something "could be better in Illustrator", that generally suggests that it's not as good as it should be, or that it's deficient in some way. It's a rather weird English idiom;) I think you probably intended to say the opposite, so you might want to reword that.  Try "can be *done* better in Illustrator", that would fix it.

Comment: @BillyKerr I've hard time with English often. Actually I meant that if you design a logo in Photoshop, you can design a good one depending on your skills and requirements. But same can also be done in Illustrator. Now I used *could* because I'm not sure if we can design all kinds of logo (that we design with Photoshop) in Illustrator too? So I'm not really sure if *can* would also imply that. I can fix it if you still think that using can is better.

Comment: If you want to say that then you could use "are probably better done in Illustrator"

Comment: @BillyKerr updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really possible to answer questions like this. But theres one, and only one, definitive reason to get photoshop.

- You need to prepare, raster images for printing

Thats it everything else is very secondary. I mean if you allready have photoshop then its fine for other tasks. But its not like there does not exist something dedicated that is better. Except perhaps photo retouching where PS is atleast par with the rest.

If all you do is edit RGB images PS may not be the best tool out there.

Mind you its not bad it has pretty nice nondestructive editing features, but sucks with nondestructive masks. So PS is a good all around tool, when you dont have anything better at hand (like its ok for calculating the steadystate of a heat transfer). PS is a bit like excel in that regard really commonly abused for shit you shouldnt do with it. But honestly for my workflow any other tool would do. I just use it because it is installed on my system and I know how to use it. Also its gui does not entirely suck either.

- But for gods sake dont use it for 3D. Thats just retarded.

In the end you should probably know how ro use it since its available nearly anywhere.